# interstitial ads is causing my app to crash

Tags: react-native, crash, admob

I am trying to add interstitial ad to my React Native app with Admob,
I proceed as stated in the guide.
https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads/displaying-ads#interstitial-ads

but I have a problem. If I use the loaded condition,

```
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }
```

the application does not load, it stays on a black screen. but If I do not use this condition, the application crashes when the ad is activated.